# После того, как эта часть программы прокомпиллировалась, переменные x1, y1, z1 становятся равны нулю

Tags: c, variable

там в конце строка `printf(..., a1, x1)` выводит `"0.000000, 0.000000"`

перед этой частью я только объявил переменные

```c
 printf("triangle1: \n");
 scanf(" %s %lf %lf %lf",&words1, &a1, &b1, &c1);
```

это условие выполняется
код:

```c
  // 1st triangle
    if (strcmp (words1, exType1)==0) {
        type1 = 1;
        if((a1 >= b1 + c1 || b1 >= a1 + c1 || c1 >= a1 + b1) || ((a1 = 0) || (b1 = 0) || (c1 = 0))){
            printf("incorrect entry\n");
            return 0;
        } else
            x1 = a1;
        y1 = b1;
        z1 = c1;
        // here
        printf("%lf, %lf\n", a1, x1);
```

Comment: Приведите [mre]. Если бы изначально его составляли, то локализовали бы ошибку сразу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы же сами присвоили нули своим переменным: `((a1 = 0) || (b1 = 0) || (c1 = 0))`. В языке Си для сравнения на равенство используется `==`.